# Campy freehub body compatibility

Tags: cassette

If I have a wheel listed as 8-10 speed Campy compatible, will a 11-speed Campagnolo cassette fit it?  I seem to remember that they didn't change their standards when they moved to 11-speed, unlike Shimano and SRAM.  I just don't have enough experience with Campy to say for sure.  Anyone out there done this conversion and can tell me for sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, all Campy 11 cassettes go on all Campy 10-compatible freehubs.

Listing it as 8-10 compatible is kind of a misnomer because you have to jump through some hoops to make an 8 work on it. It would be better to call it 9-10-11. Here's a [page worth bookmarking](http://branfordbike.com/articles/cassettes-and-cogs-pg60.htm) that I always refer back to to keep it straight.